# How to use resources dynamically in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I'm doing a simulation of an industry in Anylogic. It consists of three equal production lines, they all have the same number of processes (in the case services) and each service has a Resource attached (aka. a Machine). The products that are produced in the three lines will only be joined together in the end (at the final stock before delivery). 
However, my last process of each line can have an increase or decrease in resources (machines) when needed. For example, line 1 had a machine failure and stopped for some time and now instead of needing 4 machines to complete the order it will need 6. 
In addition, if one of this machines placed in this process breaks (because of a failure), I need the service to keep working but with less resources. So, for example, I have 4 machines in the last process of line 1, one of these machines had a break down, I would like the other 3 to keep producing.
Which possible solution can be used for this? I tried to simulate this in the service itself but it doesn't work with less resources then specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood I think you need to model the three lines separately and use three different resourcePools for your machines. Doing this you will have control over the resource capacity on every line and can change them based on any events. If your question is about how to change capacity of one line when another line fails, I suggest using the "send to flowchart" option in resource failure and you can use flowchart blocks to change capacities and execute any other code necessary.

If your 3 lines are identical, you can create a custom flowchart block and pass the resourcePool as a parameter to the custom block.This way you don't have to replicate your logic three times.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I actually already modelled the three lines (separately), but, I would like to use a common resource pool for the last process (service) of the three lines. That is because: I have 12 machines of the same type and they can be interchanged in between services (and lines) when demanded. The default is 4 machines per process (so 3 lines = 12 machines). My question is: How do I tell the system to process my products even though one of the machines inside the service has failed. Is it the best idea to use a service?

Comment: OK. One way I think you can do this without creating 12 resourcePools is to have your single resource with 12 capacity and model your failures manually. Instead of using the failure settings in resourcePool, you can create a simple logic with a source of resource tasks entering with your failure rate and seizing one of the units of the pool, delay for repair time and leave. This way your capacity is decreased but the remaining capacity can still be used.

Comment: I don't really understand your logic. I guess using a resource pool with capacity = 12 is intelligent. But, how am I supposed to create this logic? should I create it on all three lines? Thinking in a simpler way, if I had only one line and one process, and in this process I could change the capacity of resources (so have dynamical resources) how would this work?

Comment: My point is instead of trying to change the capacity of the resource when one machine fails you can seize one capacity with a different agent. Let's say you have failures that happen once every hour and take 5 min to fix. Add a source block (separate from your current logic) with arrival rate of 1, add a service block that seizes 1 capacity of your resource and has a delay of 5 min and add a sink block. Every time an agent arrives at this source you are reducing the capacity by 1 and when they leave the service block the capacity is back up.